# Channel Entries API/Model: Get created Id or Entry by Field Name

Tags: channel-entries, channel-entries-api

I hope that I can explain this succinctly. Platform is EE 2.10.1 (this is a sandbox, live version will be on 2.11.1).

I am working on an extension which is using Solspace's User Module's *user_register_end* hook. After entering the user to the member list, we need to process company information into the *Companies* channel.

I am achieving this by loading the *channel entries* and *channel fields* API and then calling the *save_entry* method:

```
ee()->load->library('api');
ee()->api->instantiate('channel_entries');
ee()->api->instantiate('channel_fields');
```

No problem so far. However, I need to process the information further and require the ID of the newly created company entry.

As far as I see, the *save_entry* method is only returning a success boolean - not the ID of the successfully created channel entry. First thought was to load the *channel_entries_model* to get the channel entry by field name. But *get_entry* only accepts the entry ID, which I don't have.
Then I reckoned, I could use the *get_recent_entries* method of the *channel_entries_model*. However, when I run it I get the following error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: EE::$cp
Filename: core/Model.php
Line Number: 50
Fatal error: Call to a member function allowed_group() on a non-object in /var/www/html/system/expressionengine/models/channel_entries_model.php on line 189
```

How can I get the ID of the channel entry that has just been created through the API? I can create a custom query using Codeigniter - but would rather not.

Thanks for guidance and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, logically the last submitted `insert` query from the API is in the `channel_data` table. This tables Primary Key is `entry_id`, so you could try this CI command after you run the `save_entry` method:

```
$new_entry_id = ee()->db->insert_id();
```

Check to make sure it's returning the correct `entry_id`. I'm assuming this works within an execution cycle and uses a stored return in the database class and the `insert_id` method doesn't actually asynchronously retrieve that insert id via another SQL query. If it does retrieve it via a second query, you might run into collisions where two processes are spawned at near the same time and something like this happens:

```
process 1: save_entry
process 2: save_entry
process 1: insert_id (get's process 2's insert_id)
process 2: insert_id (get's process 2's insert_id);
```

Check the database class in CI core the database class to verify how the last inserted id is retrieved.

Ref: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/helpers.html

**Edit**

`insert_id()` uses this function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

I think it should work fine for you. You can always do post data validation if you feel it's truly necessary, once you have your `entry_id`.

**Edit**

Try this after you save a new entry:

```
$new_entry_id = ee()->api_channel_entries->entry_id;
```

Comment: I tried using insert_id. But called from the extension, the result is 0.

Comment: Edited, try grabbing that prop.

Comment: @jrothafer is correct, after an entry is saved, the `$entry_id` class property should be set on the `Api_channel_entries` object.

Comment: I will try that. Already off work. Will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Using the $entry_id property on the Api_channel_entries object does the trick! Thanks.